# Simple Java Card Game - Trouble shuffling the deck (array)

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java and I'm having trouble understanding how to shuffle an array (or my deck array). I've tried using the `Random` class, but it's not doing the thing for me. Anyway, here go the classes I've created:

*CardGame*

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CardGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // final int SPADES = 0, HEARTS = 1, DIAMONS = 2, CLUBS = 3;
        final int ACE = 1, TWO = 2, THREE = 3, FOUR = 4, FIVE = 5, SIX = 6, SEVEN = 7, EIGHT = 8;
        final int NINE = 9, TEN = 10, JACK = 11, QUEEN = 12, KING = 13;

        Random rand = new Random();

        int[][] deck = {
                { ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING },

                player1.setHand(deck[i][randIndex]);
                player2.setHand(deck[i][randIndex]);
                player3.setHand(deck[i][randIndex]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(player1.getHand());
        System.out.println(player2.getHand());
        System.out.println(player3.getHand());
    }
}
```

*Player*

```
public class Player {

    final int MAX_HAND = 6;

    private String playerName;
    private int playerHand[] = new int[MAX_HAND];

    public Player(String name) {
        playerName = name;
    }

    public void setHand(int card) {

        int currentLength = playerHand.length;

        if (currentLength == MAX_HAND) {
            return;
        }

        playerHand[currentLength] = card;
    }

    public String getHand() {

        String cardN
                case 8:     cardNames += "Eight";   break;
                case 9:     cardNames += "Nine";    break;
                case 10:    cardNames += "Ten";     break;
                case 11:    cardNames += "Jack";    break;
                case 12:    cardNames += "Queen";   break;
                case 13:    cardNames += "King";    break;
            }

            if (i < playerHand.length - 2) {
                cardNames += ", ";
            }

        }

        return playerName + " has " + cardNames + " on his hand.";
    }
}
```

The result is always:

> Name1 has Ace, Two, Three, Four and Five on his hand. 
> Name2 has Ace,
>   Two, Three, Four and Five on his hand. 
> Name3 has Ace, Two, Three, Four
>   and Five on his hand.

What is it that I'm doing wrong to generate a random index for the inner array of `deck`?

Thank you.

Comment: Updated the question. It's outputting the same result all the time.

Comment: Take a look at [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: I have to stick to arrays for now. It's just this randomness part that's troubling me, otherwise this simple game would have been considered finished.

Comment: Why are you using an inner loop with `j` when it's never used?

Comment: It was being used earlier, now it's not. Does the presence of that loop make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `switch (i)` with `switch (playerHand[i])` in your `getHand()` method and also call `nextInt()` for every player not just once on each iteration.

Change `setHand()` into

```
int index = 0;
public void addCard(int card) {
  if (index == MAX_HAND) {
            return;
  }
  playerHand[index++] = card;
}
```

Comment: now the result became like `Name1 has , , ,  and  on his hand.
Name2 has , , ,  and  on his hand.
Name3 has , , ,  and  on his hand.`. What is going wrong? It's confusing...

Comment: @Aborted thats because your are not really setting the cards. See my edit.

Comment: This is almost working! the only problem is that it's setting 4 random cards instead of 5.

Comment: I got this mixed by removing the increment from the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call rand.nextInt after each time you set a card.

```
                player1.setHand(deck[i][rand.nextInt(deck[i].length)]);
                player2.setHand(deck[i][rand.nextInt(deck[i].length)]);
                player3.setHand(deck[i][rand.nextInt(deck[i].length)]);
```

Comment: The result is the same.